# Rails ActiveRecord - How to set association save order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a weird relationship that needs to be maintained for legacy processes.

I'm trying to figure out how to create the relationship given the new model association.

New Relationship Setup

```
Machine
  has_many MachineReadings
  has_many Disks
    has_many DiskReadings
```

Old Relationship Setup

```
Machine
  has_many MachineReadings
    has_many DiskReadings
  has_many Disks
```

The problem is data will come in on the Machine model as nested attributes using the new relationship setup.  I need to update the machine_reading_id in the DiskReading model so the old association can continue to be used.

I tried doing this via an after_save hook that would traverse back up to the machine and then down to the readings to get the machine_reading.id so I could populate the DiskReading model.  However, the associations aren't being saved in the order I would expect.  They are saving the Disks & DiskReadings before saving the MachineReadings.  So when I go after the machine_reading.id it hasn't been written and thus I am unable to get access to it.

For example:

```
#machine_disk_reading.rb
after_save :build_old_relationship

def build_old_relationship
  self.machine_reading_id = self.disk.machine.readings.find_by_date_time(self.date_time).id
end
```

Comment: If you want the models to be saved in a specific order: couldn't you validate manually, and save, each one in the order you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this.  Must be done manually.